# Introducing extra type-id as compile-time optimization

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a difference in compile time duration, when I intensively use similarly instantiated `result_type_t`'s defined as follows:

- First form:

  ```
  template< typename F, typename ...Args >
  using result_type_t = decltype(std::declval< F >()(std::declval< Args >()...));
  ```
- Second form:

  ```
  template< typename F, typename ...Args >
  struct result_type
  {
      using type = decltype(std::declval< F >()(std::declval< Args >()...));
  };

  template< typename F, typename ...Args >
  using result_type_t = typename result_type< F, Args... >::type;
  ```

?

What I mean is using the same instantiation of `result_type_t< F, Args... >` repeatedly for the same `F, Args...` template arguments in diverse places of the same translation unit. For the type alias case there no new [*type-id*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming) introduced and, on my mind, compiler will deduce `decltype()` every time again and again when encounters it. For the second version there is corresponding [*type-id*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Type_naming) `result_type< F, Args... >` saved somewhere in "symbol table" for a current translation unit after its first instantiation and its member typedef `type` is ready to use instantly (i.e. is "precalculated"). Am I right?

Comment: g++ doesn't treat the 2 as equivalent for SFINAE: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa0ce7481287eaf3)

Comment: @Jarod42 Please, don't consider particular example. The question is mostly about type-ids and compilation.

Comment: Not sure about the compiler, but for eyes `std::result_of_t<F(Args&&...)>` reads much better

Comment: @bobah Irrelevant to the essence of the question.

Comment: I would't be surprised, if the second version would indeed be (minimally) faster, provided, that the structure remains in cache during compilation. However, as with all performance related questions, I fear you'll have to measure it for your specific case. I  would expect the answer to be compiler, code and system dependent

Comment: Short inspection of Clang's code suggests that it looks up instantiation of the template alias exactly the same way as it looks up instantiations of class templates. In other words, there is no overhead for repeated `decltype` in the first form, and so it should actually be minimally faster due to not introducing an additional type. However, I'm not 100% sure that I understood the code correctly, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Can you provide relevant file and line numbers (say, on github repo mirror of clang)? It would be interesting to sink deeper into a relevant code.

Comment: That's a really weird use of the term *type-id*, not the least because `decltype(std::declval< F >()(std::declval< Args >()...))` is as much as a *type-id* as `typename result_type< F, Args... >::type` or `result_type< F, Args... >`. Do you mean something like "class template specialization"?

Comment: @T.C. Not sure, but I mean something, which finally can be found in output of `nm` utility, if exported at all. Something, that can be a part of (mangled) function name. Something, that can make sense during overloading resoulution. Something unique. Is there suitable term?